# yum/dnf install fail

Tags: centos, rpm, dnf

I was using centOS8 and try to execute `yum install -y gcc tcl` and failed. The error shows it has some problem with signature check or something at rpm install process.The console log is like
`error: /var/cache/dnf/base-82351eca59c28538/packages/cpp-8.5.0-21.el8.x86_64.rpm: signature hdr data: BAD, no. of bytes(9088) out of range`
and
`Error: GPG check FAILED`.
I tried to upgrade my rpm installer and get same problem, and `yum update` didn't work either. I tried to use `--nogpgcheck`, it still didn't work.

Comment: Try first `yum clean all` and then again try to install

Answer (score 0):

You have two issues here:

1- `error: /var/cache/dnf/base-82351eca59c28538/packages/cpp-8.5.0-21.el8.x86_64.rpm: signature hdr data: BAD, no. of bytes(9088) out of range`: there are multiple solutions for it:

- execute the following command `dnf clean all`
- if the command above did not fix the issue: then follow the steps below:

  - `curl ttps://vault.centos.org/8.5.2111/BaseOS/x86_64/os/Packages/centos-gpg-keys-8-3.el8.noarch.rpm -o centos-gpg-keys-8-3.el8.noarch.rpm` assuming you are using Centos 8 you can get the latest version of this by visiting the main website.
  - `rpm -i centos-gpg-keys-8-3.el8.noarch.rpm`  (again if the version is different then you need to adjust the package name)

2- `Error: GPG check FAILED` there are a couple of solutions for it.

- `sudo dnfclean all` , `sudo yum clean metadata` , and `dnf clean all` then rename `/etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-centosofficial` then try to install your package again.
- Disable `GPG check` temporarily if the solution above did not fix the issue
- Check if you have a security application that might cause an issue such as Zscaler.

Comment: I indeed tried clean all command and still not function.
I also tried to install local package here's my console log.
`rpm -i rpm-build-4.14.3-31.el8.x86_64.rpm`

`error: rpm-build-4.14.3-31.el8.x86_64.rpm: signature hdr data: BAD, no. of bytes(16520) out of range
error: rpm-build-4.14.3-31.el8.x86_64.rpm cannot be installed`

Comment: @Toxice_w_ try to rebuild RPM DB using the following command `sudo rpm --rebuilddb`